# Microsoft Graph API - AuthenticationError : Error authenticating with resource

Tags: jwt, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to get list of events of a user using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users//events but getting an **Error authenticating with resource** error.

[image]

Everything was working until Monday. I have a work Microsoft account.

I cannot event create update, cancel or delete an event. All API request gives the same error.

I am only able to get the Token using https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

I have checked my token using https://jwt.ms and the roles are

[image]

How can I see the detailed error or what is an issue here? Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler? What does it say?

Comment: Getting the same error using Fiddler

Comment: @UmerWaqar Did you find out what was causing the problem? It seems I'm encountering the same issue right now (although with another endpoint), everything worked perfectly a few hours ago, but now I'm getting this authentication error.

Comment: @DanielSklenitzka my secret key got expired so I created another one.

Comment: Thanks. I checked that and it was still okay. Anyway, an hour later it started working again...still not sure what was the problem.